# Generate JSON from PDO without quotation marks

Tags: php, sql, json, pdo

I have a PDO code that is fetching tables from SQL and outputs a JSON.

The output gives me good results but with quotation marks.

How can i eliminate the quotations from the field names like this example:

> (period: "2014 Q1")

PHP Code:

```
<?php


  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
  $statement=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM budget");
  $statement->execute();
  $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json=json_encode($results, 128);

  header('Content-type: application/json');

  echo $json;

  ?>
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "period": "2011 Q1",
        "sales": "1400",
        "profit": "400"
    },
    {
        "period": "2011 Q2",
        "sales": "1100",
        "profit": "600"
    },
    {
        "period": "2011 Q3",
        "sales": "1600",
        "profit": "500"
    },
    {
        "period": "2011 Q4",
        "sales": "1200",
        "profit": "400"
    },
    {
        "period": "2012 Q1",
        "sales": "1550",
        "profit": "800"
    }
]
```

Comment: Without quotation marks it would not be valid JSON. Why are the quotes causing you issues?

Comment: I use a chart.js file that is receiving 'data: period: "2015 Q1"..but its failing when i connect the JSON to it so it must be the quotations if i'm not misstaking

Comment: You are likely mistaken as plugins and libraries which use JSON are aware of how proper JSON is formatted. What kinds of errors are you getting?

Comment: I suspect you're not parsing the JSON in the Javascript before passing it to the charting function. Show your Javascript code.